# C++11, using printf("%p", *this) in member function will call destructor, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

class Test
{
public:
    int *arr;
    virtual void f1(){};
    void f2(){};

    Test()
    {
        arr = new int[5];
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        delete[] arr;
        arr = nullptr;
        std::cout << " call ~Test()" << std::endl;
    }

    void show()
    {
        printf("start show\n");

        printf("*this address:%p\n", *this);//【1】

        printf("exit show\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test *c = new Test();
    c->show();

    //c->~Test();//【2】
    c->arr[1] = 5;//【3】

    while (1);
    std::cout << "return 0;" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```c
/*
Compiler version: gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3 Ubuntu 1 ~ 18.04)
Compile and run under ubuntu18:
$ g++ destractor.cpp -o destractor -std=c++11
$./destractor 
start show
*this address:0x7fffbe1cb2f0
 call ~Test()
exit show
*/
```

Please pay attention to the code at position [1], as long as it is used, the destructor will be called.

Assuming that the destructor is really called, it is reasonable to say that when code at position [3] is executed, there will be a segment error, because arr has been released, but there is no segment error here. If the annotation at position [2] is removed, the program will execute to position [3], and a segment error will occur.
Then the question is coming:
Q1: Why does the code at position [1] call the destructor?
Q2: It seems that calling destructor at [1] is different from that at [2]. Although destructor is called at [1], there will be no segment error, but it will lead to segment error at [2]. Although destructor is called at position [1], why can't arr's memory be released?

Thank you!

Comment: `*this` isn't a pointer, it's a `Test`.  Did you mean to `printf("%p", this);` instead?

Comment: Compile with warnings. Add at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` to save yourself hours of headache.

Comment: When you pass the `Test` object `*this` to `printf`, it's passed by value, so a copy has to be made.  The compiler calls the implicit trivial copy constructor to create it, then naturally calls your destructor to destruct it.  This is not so good because only the pointer `arr` was copied by the trivial copy constructor, so indeed you will use it after deleting, which is UB (may or may not segfault).  Of course the whole thing is undefined behavior before that because `printf` can't accept an object of type `Test` passed to it, when a pointer is expected.

Comment: You invoke Undefined Behaviour  and unspecified behaviour in your code: `printf("*this address:%p\n", *this);` should use `this` (a pointer) and not `*this` (the object). This explicitely invokes UB. Later `while(1);` is an endless loop with no side effect that the compiler can optimize out. Once UB has come in, you can no longer blame the compiler for whatever result...

Comment: hi,I modified the constructor. If the constructor is called, static int cnt will be printed.   
`
int Test::cnt = 0;
   
 Test()
    {
        ++cnt;
        arr = new int[5];
        std::cout << "call Test() " << "cnt = " << cnt << std::endl;
       
    }`
，I didn't see the constructor called many times. Does this mean that `printf` didn't construct a temporary `Test`?@NateEldredge

Comment: You should do this with a copy constructor, because the class be copied, not construct from scratch.

Comment: use copy constructor, it is ok.@churill